# Save iframe content as text file

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, text-files, parent-child

How do you save the content of an iframe as a text file? Currently i only know ways to save the content of the webpage itself, but not any child iframes. I'm thinking some javascript, PHP and/or HTML5.

Comment: Hi 

Is there any specific reason why you would want to?
Do you need the ability to do it for a project or do you just want to save the content this one time (for yourself)?

Thanks

Comment: you will laugh, but the content of the iframe is a text file

Comment: You can download a webpage, look for an iframe element in it, get its src tag and download the contents in a separate request. You should also take into account cases when the src is relative to the current path, but the entire endeavor shouldn't be too much hassle :)

Comment: @TobyOsborne It's for a project and i wan't the code to be saved on the server, when the webpage is loaded.

Comment: @johnSmith Seriosly? Then how to save it? (on server)

Comment: @Vasil Not what i want... Need to save the code within the iframe as a text file on the server when the webpage is loaded. But thanks! ;)

Comment: @user3457061 as Vasil stated you could use php to download the text and then you can save it in the filesystem as .txt or whatever, here you go :  http://www.php.net/file_get_contents   and  for saving  http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score -1):

Using PHP and Javascript you can do this easily

**Javascript (JQuery)**

```
var data = document.getelementbyid("idofiframe").html();
var url = 'write.php';
$.ajax({url: url,type:"POST",data: data});
```

**PHP**

```
//Log all Proxy Requests
$file = 'file.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$current .= date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). ",".file_get_contents('php://input')."\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```